# syntax error near unexpected token `(' in below code

Tags: bash, shell

I have very small shell script.When I am running it run flow. it is giving "syntax error near unexpected token `(". Very basic question but sorry not able to figure out.

```
foreach i ( `cat list407`)
mkdir cells/${i}
 cp /<path>/$i/${i}.gds cells/${i}/${i}.gds
end
```

Error:

```
flow: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `('
flow: line 1: `foreach i ( `cat list407`)'
```

Comment: You seem to be executing `csh` syntax using `bash`.

Answer (score 4):

You've used `csh` syntax for execution using `bash` which is causing the error.

Either use `csh` to execute your script, or using `bash` say:

```
while read -r i; do
  mkdir "cells/${i}"
  cp "/<path>/${i}/${i}.gds" "cells/${i}/${i}.gds"
done < list407
```

Comment: Thx for quick response. Yes I did this mistake.

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in $(cat list407); do
  mkdir cells/${i};
  cp /<path>/$i/${i}.gds cells/${i}/${i}.gds;
done
```

Comment: Bad practice. **Never** use command substitution with `for` loop. Also, **never** read a file with `for` loop, always use `while` for this purpose. refer [this](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29)